# Why is there an {untagged} tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just came across a question which didn't have any tags apart from [untagged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).  I was a bit baffled by this and clicked the tag to find that there about ten questions with this tag (and no others).

Some of these posts are migrated from other sites and I believe that the [untagged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a result of migration stripping all non-existent tags as also discussed here [Problematic migration change](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/problematic-migration-change).

However, [this question by Lars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245708/hieroglf-vs-t1-fontenc) is also [untagged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and has *not* been migrated which means that users can actively select it.  The [untagged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is an [oxymoron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) and its pure existence allows users to tag questions with it which makes even less sense.

I think we should get rid of this, in my opinion, absolutely nonsensical tag and replace it with a, e.g., [migrated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrated) tag.

Comment: I would assume that it is used as dummy tag, since each question must have at least one tag?

Comment: To drive logicians crazy, I assume.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Every question has to be tagged, but it's possible for all valid tags to 'vanish'. This is most obviously true for migration but can also occur if tag cleanup removes a tag. In these cases questions will be marked 'untagged'.

Comment: If there was a review queue for "edits needed" questions, it would make sense for [tag:untagged] questions to make it there; unfortunately none of the current queues is suitable for this.

Answer (score 11):

There are now only five questions in the [untagged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. I've edited all the ones I could to get rid of that tag (and otherwise improve them). The ones that are left are closed (4 out of the 5) or a duplicate (1 out of the 5; it's merged with another question, I think) so I cannot edit them. I don't know if this is an "amount of rep" thing; if so, maybe someone else can edit those.

Comment: Reaching 10000 rep it is possible to edit `tags` inline, without editing the post body.

Comment: Yes, I remember letting some of your edits through (although I believe it requires two 2k+ users to approve) - thank you very much for taking the time to do this, it's much appreciated :)

Comment: It's not rep amount here; the questions are *locked*, which means that even mods can't edit them.